# bash: syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I have this alias in .bashrc:

```
alias clone='while ! rsync --rsh=ssh -avP --delete --stats --compress-level=9 $1/ $2:$3 | grep -q "Number of files transferred: 0" ; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done'
```

Got error when I do this:

```
clone /d/root/tmp cowboy@hicow.com /temp
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `/d/root/tmp'
```

Everything works fine if I put this in a script file:

```
#!/bin/sh
while ! rsync --rsh=ssh -avP --delete --stats --compress-level=9 $1/ $2:$3 | grep -q "Number of files transferred: 0" ; do echo -n .; sleep 1; done
```

and execute the script file like so:

```
./clonescript /d/root/tmp cowboy@hicow.com /temp
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases do not have positional arguments. create a function instead.

```
clone() {
  while ...
   ...
}
```